# How to convert Delta file format to Parquet File only

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, parquet, azure-synapse, delta-lake

Delta Lake is the default storage format.I understand how to convert a parquet to Delta.

My question is is there any way to revert it back to parquet.Any options ?

What I need is I want  single parquet file while writing .Do not need the extra log file !

Comment: what about using `.format("parquet")` when writing?

Comment: Also, the default format for load/save operations for spark is parquet, and not delta. [Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#generic-loadsave-functions)

Answer (score 4):

If you run vacuum on the table and delete the log folder, you end up with regular parquet files.

Comment: Wdym by versioning?

Comment: By version, I meant an older version of delta table. However, I did not know entirely what Vaccum command did. Seems like it will take care of this by removing all parquet files that are no longer in the latest state/version of the transaction log. 
So, your statement is indeed correct. [More about Vaccum command](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html)

Comment: Yes, vacuum gets rid of all those files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back from Delta to Parquet you need to:

1. Get rid of old versions of the data.
2. Clean the delta_log folder.

For 1 you can run the following command `VACUUM <table> RETAIN 0 HOURS`. But there is a safe check that will prevent you from running vacuums with less than 168 hours (7 days). To avoid this you can set the following spark property:
`spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")`

For 2 just delete the folder.

More info: https://delta.io/blog/remove-files-delta-lake-vacuum-command/