# How to convert delta to parquet

Tags: delta-lake

Hope it is not a dumb question. I have some use case that would require converting delta to parquet.

The most related answer I got from online [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173070/how-to-convert-delta-file-format-to-parquet-file-only) is (1) call `Vacuum` with retention 0 hours to only keep the latest version (2) delete `delta_log` directory that contains the metadata and transaction logs for delta format.

May I know whether that is normally enough to convert delta to parquet?

I did some online searching and learning and I still have below questions

For parquet format, we have multiple `.parquet` files, all of them together representing the whole dataset.

For delta, we have multiple "versions" of parquets. Does each of them representing the whole dataset? Or more correctly, each of them contains different state of the dataset (e.g. snapshot). How `Vacuum` deals with these `.parquet` files in detail?

Thanks

Comment: did you perform "MERGE", "UPDATE" or "DELETE" operations? If you did not (i.e. only was doing INSERT) then you do not have to VACUUM at all. Note, vacuuming with 0 retention is official way https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#-convert-a-delta-table-to-a-parquet-table to convert to parquet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the delta table into a df, and write it back in parquet format.

This example uses pyspark code:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-table")
df.write.parquet("/tmp/parquet-table.parquet")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. May I know whether we still need to call `Vaccum` or converting to dataframe then parquet will have duplicate rows (e.g. including the delete rows)?

Comment: Since you're converting the delta table explicitly to parquet format, the generated parquet file is not related to delta in anyway, hence no need to run vaccum etc. Assuming the latest version/snapshot of delta didn't have any duplicates, the generated parquet won't have any either